# Unable to post a release in Github with an error relating to AWS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, git, github, amazon-ec2

[This is the error I am receiving in Github when I try to publish a release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qipf.png)

I am not sure why this error is occuring as I haven't made any changes in my code or AWS, but now this error has occured out of nowhere. Has anyone experienced this before and know the solution?

Thank you!

I have not tried to make any changes yet

Comment: The link at the top of the message contains the image of the error I am receiving. 

Here is a copy and paste of the error:

Comment: Run copilot deploy
  copilot deploy
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: us-east-1
    AWS_REGION: us-east-1
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ***
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ***
Found only one workload, defaulting to: admin
✘ get workspace environments: read directory /home/runner/work/admin-console/admin-console/copilot/environments: open /home/runner/work/admin-console/admin-console/copilot/environments: no such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Comment: Please [edit] and put the text of the error message into the question.